# Shadow of vote to close button still displays after button is pressed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When you press the VtC button, the button's background disappears but the shadow remains:

[image: button turns white but shadow stays]

The same appears to be happening to all buttons on the main site.

On meta sites, the buttons turn grey instead of disappearing, so the shadow does not look out of place. Maybe this is the solution to this problem?

[image]

*Note: I did find [a similar bug](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/773/save-edits-button-has-a-green-border-on-top-when-pressed) on another site, so I wouldn't be surprised if there is a problem with all buttons across the network.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer an issue. With the rollout of the network-wide theming update, the button styles were updated significantly, and the new button doesn't exhibit the same problem:

[image: Updated Button style]

Arqade's site design rollout was announced/discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182).